# How to configure Flask Server with NGINX and React app on Heroku?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, flask, heroku

I am trying to deploy an application on heroku that uses two docker containers.

- Container 1: Client/Frontend container - builds the react application and nginx server
- Container 2: API/Backend Flask container - runs Gunicorn flask application

My goal is to send API requests from the React front-end to the Flask backend using a reverse proxy to the backend server.

Both containers are up and running successfully on Heroku but my API requests are failing to the backend server. This configuration was working fine running in a local environment but I am having trouble transitioning this over to the Heroku environment. My NGINX.conf.template file is below

```
upstream flask_backend {
        appname.herokuapp.com;
    }

 server {
    listen ${PORT};
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        add_header Cache-Control "no-cache";
    }

    location /static {
        expires 1y;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

     location /api {
            proxy_pass https://flask_backend;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
     }

     location /socket.io {
            proxy_pass https://flask_backend;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
     }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

}
```

Currently any API request from my front-end results in a 503 error. This is my first time working with Heroku and using a configuration like this.

Does anyone have any suggestions or any ideas of what the issue may be? If I can provide any other information regarding the configuration please let me know!

Comment: You should have a look inside the log files. At one hand have a look at the nginx log files if it gets the requests you send successfully. Then have a look at your backend logs which requests are getting there, if any do. Can we have a look how you start the containers with which parameters? And is the nginx proxy a seperate container? If not you should use a seperate container for nginx reverse proxy, as every service should have its separate container.